# Finding answer in Spinner List

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

I'm doing a planner app the home page or the main activity is a list view when you click add button it will go to another window the first is spinner (dropdownlist) there are 4 categories. If I click one of them and click save, it must save to the list view in the main activity.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'm having some trouble in my spinner or dropdown list how will it show it in my main activity inside the listview.